# Good literature on the implications of philosophy of mind for ethics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, metaethics

It seems to me that positions in philosophy of mind have implications for ethics that most of the literature I have read does not explore. Some examples:

1. Does mental externalism imply torturing a brain in a vat is okay?
2. Do property dualism and functionalism or physicalism have different implications for whether cognitively simpler creatures (like insects) have moral standing?
3. Is eliminative materialism compatible with any talk of norms whatsoever?
4. Perhaps most obviously and most often addressed, what do different views in philosophy of mind have to stay about the moral status of AI?

Comment: Too many questions for one post. There is vast literature on the relationship between philosophy of mind and ethics, see e.g. [SEP, Neuroethics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/neuroethics/), [Shaffer, Philosophy of Mind and Some Ethical Implications](https://soar.suny.edu/handle/20.500.12648/3399), [Farah, Neuroethics and the Problem of Other Minds](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12152-008-9006-8), and the whole volume [Moral Foundations of Philosophy of Mind](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-18492-6).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.